# iOS 11 - Hit Test based upon touch type

Tags: ios, swift

Quick question: Is there an easy way to hit test in a UIView with the touch information? I have one UIView that I need pencil to respond to, I have another that I need the finger to respond to (PDFView) I want a way to forward the touch to each view based upon the touch type. Thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

You can use UIResponder's method `touchesBegan(_:with:)`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan

or `UITapGestureRecognizer`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1620009-touchesbegan
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624214-gesturerecognizer

Information about touch type you can take from `UITouch` object: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch/touchtype

Comment: So that doesn't quite answer the question. The hitTest function doesn't provide the touches from the event, and therefore you can't check the touch type.

Comment: True, `hitTest(_:with:)` event returns empty touches set. But you can still get touch from `UIGestureRecognizer`. You need to override `touchesBegan(_:with:)` method and check `touches` object.

Comment: all touchesBegan will be called after all hitTest, even those inside gesture recognizers. this is not helpful.